# Jquery - How Do I Insert a Character into an input

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me out with this please...

I am doing a web form. I would like to insert the dollar sign into some INPUTs that have a numberfield class.  I want the user's content to follow the dollar sign or course.

This inserts the dollar sign OK, but the content ends up in front of it.

```
$('input.numberfield').val('$');
```

NOTE - the dollar sign is required because this is financial data (nothing to do with jquery! :) )

in other words - someone types in '100' and it becomes '$100')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('input.numberfield').each(function() {
  $(this).val('$' + $(this).val());
}
```

In 1.4, a simple more complete solution for your scenario:

```
 $('input.numberfield').keyup(function() {
   $(this).val(function(i,v) {
     return '$' + v.replace('$',''); //remove exisiting, add back.
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

Why make your life complex? Just put the dollar sign into the HTML *outside* of the input element...

```
<span style="border: inset 1px black; padding: 1px;">
  $<input style="border: none; padding: 0;">
</span>
```

Comment: I think the problem is how to add it inside <input>

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and use a regular expression to add a `$` to the front if there isn't one there already:

```
$("input.numberfield").val(function(i, val) {
  return val.replace(/^\s*(?!\$)/, "$");
});
```

The above regex means replace a sequence of white space at the beginning of the value that *isn't* followed by a dollar sign with a dollar sign. This would work too:

```
$("input.numberfield").val(function(i, val) {
  return val.replace(/^\s*(\$)?/, "$");
});
```

Comment: these functions are injecting the actual code into my INPUTSs!

(not sure whats going on there)

Thanks for the very quick responses.  What I was wanting was that, when you onlick (anywhere in the input), the cursor would jump to the right side of the dollar sign.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Jared: these aren't injecting the actual code into the inputs. Read the linked documentation for `val()`. They're injecting the **return value** from the function into the inputs. It's a shorthand form of `each(function() { $(this).val(...) }` essentially.

Comment: in my scrip they're injecting the dollar sign into the input value that is being passed with the form, so the form is breaking. what I'm trying to do is add a percentage symbol after my value, that isn't passed with the form. so far i'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
var store = $("input.numberfield");
store.val("$" + store.val());
```